# How resolve constructor params if create instance in runtime?

Tags: c#, azure, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have azure worked role, I have list of types and I create it in runtime. 
I need use IoC (structuremap) to initialize constructor params.
Now I have this class:

```
public class BuildCompletedFormatter1
    {
        private readonly IBuildService _buildService;
        private readonly IProjectService _projectService;

        public BuildCompletedFormatter(IContainer container) : base(container)
        {
            _projectService = container.GetInstance<IProjectService>();
            _buildService = container.GetInstance<IBuildService>();
        }
}
```

and I now create:

```
var type = instanse.GetType();
object instantiatedType = Activator.CreateInstance(type, container);
return instantiatedType;
```

But I need initialize constructor with zero or more paramas. 
My formatters don't need know about IContaiiner

I want have the params in constructor:

```
public class BuildCompletedFormatter2
        {
            private readonly IBuildService _buildService;
            private readonly IProjectService _projectService;

            public BuildCompletedFormatter(IProjectService projectService, IBuildService buildService)
            {
                _projectService = projectService;
                _buildService = buildService;
            }
    }
```

Comment: So what exactly your problem? Clearly you've checked MSDN [CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (also sample code in the post makes no sense because none of `CreateInstance` methods take object as parameter)... Please clarify.

Comment: I don't what pass IContainer container, I need pass Service and whhen I create instance IoC automaticaly pass needed params

Comment: You already have `instanse`. Why do you need to generate a new object from its type?

Comment: Please consider providing sample of the code that you want to get working. It is very hard to figure out what you want and what you have available. I.e. in `BuildCompletedFormatter(IContainer container)` constructor takes `container` as argument - I don't see how you can pass anything else there ...

Comment: You've now posted two different versions of `BuildCompletedFormatter`. Which one is it? Also: none of them compile because they call `base(container)`, but don't derive from any specific base class.

Comment: I don't want use IContainer, I can remove IContainer in base class. I need functional for create instanse with interfaces of services

Comment: Since you state that you 'need' to use a DI Container (StructureMap), then can't you ask it to create the object for you?

Comment: @Mark Seemann, lol, I just need ask IContainer.GetInstatse<BuildCompletedFormatter2>(). Thanks ))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the type you want to resolve with StructureMap, you should be able to create it as easily as:

```
var container = new Container();
container.Configure(r => r.For<IProjectService>().Use<MyProjectService>());
container.Configure(r => r.For<IBuildService>().Use<MyBuildService>());

var fmt = container.GetInstance<BuildCompletedFormatter2>();
```

It's been a long time since I last looked at StructureMap, so my use of its API may be outdated, but the general concepts ought to remain the same.